# How to render a taxonomy field in a Views' PHP code field?

Tags: views

In Views PHP code, I could render a field by :-

```
<?php
  print drupal_render($data->field_field_my_text); 
?>
```

But this only seems to work field with type Text. I have a field which is Taxonomy (Term Reference) and I am trying to output that through the above code but it's not working.

This is what I wrote:-

```
<?php
      print drupal_render($data->field_field_my_category); 
    ?>
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. Any idea what I should do here?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of adding PHP code in database I would suggest write a template file for it and write your code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment because of rep..
Use [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and use the dpm() function in your php for some debugging, drill down and find the value you are looking for then double click the value in the debug widget and it should tell you your field value.

here's my guess:

`$data->field_field_my_category[0]['raw']['value'];`

Might be slightly different if it's a tax term but devel is your best friend and you should use it quite frequently. Stop guessing and start debuging (best advice i've ever gotten).